# Where is the error in my code?

Tags: java

```
/** Yields: a String that contains each capital Letter (in 'A'..'Z') whose representation is prime */

public static String primeChars() {
    String s = "";

    // inv: s contains each capital in "A'..c-1 whose representation is prime

    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c=(char)(c+1)) {
        if (Loops.isPrime((int)c) == true) {
            s= s+1;
        }
    }

    // s contains each capital in 'A' ..'Z' whose rep is a prime

    return s; 
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Can you write a little introduction about what you are trying to do maybe... and what error you get?

Comment: also remove `==true` from your condition.

Comment: I don't know.  Where _is_ the error in your code?  (A stack trace might answer that question.)

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm not too sure.  I'm a newbie to Java.  @Adil Soomro, why would I remove ==true?

Comment: @LuluLarson: Actually it was not an error, I suggested you for the optimization of your code. Becasue `isPrime()` will return you `boolean`, since you can directly call `if(true)` or `if(false)`, then no need to double comparison.

Comment: @AdilSoomro, it's not an optimization.  I'm pretty confident either the compiler or the JIT can remove the `== true`.  It's good advice, but to benefit human readers.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
s = s + c;
```

You want to concatenate the character if it's prime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to write

```
s = s + c
```

Then do you want evaluate isPrime on char ASCII code or on char position?
That is do you want 'A' value is 65 (the ASCII code) or 1 (because A is the 1 letter)?
In the first case fix

```
s = s + c
```

it is enough, but in second you need change also

```
if (Loops.isPrime((int)c)==true) {
```

and do not pass "c" but

```
if (Loops.isPrime( (int)c - (int)'A' + 1 )==true) {
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  I wanted it in the ASCII code.  Thank you for the extra info!